# Темный режим доступен на Stack Overflow на русском!

Tags: обсуждение, тёмная-тема

Что может быть сложного в создании темной темы для сайта? Ведь даже  [сторонние расширения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336626/274323) прекрасно справляются с задачей! Да, но в реальности, каждый раз, когда мы задумывались над реализацией, всплывало [большое количество сложных технических задач](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297). Ситуация изменилась с появлением проекта «[Stacks styles](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/)» и переводом на него значительной части сайта. Первый раз всерьез мы задумались о возможности поддержки темного режима в июле 2019. [Зимой 2020 Аарон провел исследование](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/356) и уже в марте [бета версия темной темы была доступна на Stack Overflow на английском](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/564240).

Я рад сообщить, что с сегодняшнего дня темный режим доступен для всех зарегистрированных участников Stack Overflow на русском!

[image: Снимок экрана темного режима]

На данный момент темный режим доступен только на основном сайте (на Stack Overflow на всех языках). Возможность поддержки темного режима на метах, включая MSE, как и других сайтах сети все еще остается под вопросом.

[Больше информации про создание темного режима в статье Аарона в блоге.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/)

#### Как активировать темный режим?

Чтобы активировать темный режим, перейдите на страницу вашего профиля на Stack Overflow на русском. Далее на вкладку «Править», прокрутите вниз до [«Персональные настройки»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) в разделе «Настройки сайта» и найдите раздел «Тема» вверху страницы. У вас есть три варианта - светлый, темный и «системные настройки», которые изменят тему в зависимости от предпочтений вашей системы.

[image: Настройки сайта]

(Нажмите на изображение, для просмотра gif)

#### Как сообщить об ошибке?

Если вы обнаружили дефект, пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на Мета Stack Overflow на русском или Мета Stack Overflow на английском.

Мы будем очень рады услышать, что вы думаете!

Comment: будет ли темная тема для мобильной версии сайта?

Comment: @Danis мобильная версия, имхо, не развивается вовсе. По идее, адаптивный дизайн в пределе должен снять необходимость наличия мобильной версии на корню. Но так как её не развивают, то и поддержка выходит нулевая, поэтому и искоренять, наверное, не будут даже, если адаптивный дизайн достигнет своего апогея.

Comment: Возникающие хотелки куда писать? 1) Пожалуй, я бы поменял цвета текста не просмотренного и уже посещенного вопросов на главной странице. Т.е. начальный цвет сдел бы более ярким.

Comment: Конечно, идеально было бы иметь редактор темы, с возможностью установки в RGB цветов элементов (background, foreground и т.д.)

Comment: Ура! Давно ждал! Было бы ещё более замечательно иметь и для «Meta» такие настройки, а также для мобильной версии.

Comment: @avp Напишите, пожалуйста, отдельным вопросом либо на нашей Мете, либо на Мете Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 12):

По-моему с цветами темы всё же что-то не то. В частности цвет шрифтов мне кажется слишком ярким для тёмного фона. Сразу начинает резать глаза. При этом текст в правой панели выглядит не таким ядовидым, как в самих вопросах. Может быть дело ещё в сглаживании шрифтов.

Смотрел со страницы на вкладке [Вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions), а не с главной, т.к. на главной выводятся только заголовки вопросов.

Comment: Что-то как-то сложно синий на чёрном воспринимается, ага.

Comment: Попробовал. Пока неперевычно и поэтому все как-то плохо воспринимается.

Comment: @avp я при этом работаю в темной теме Visual Studio, но всё равно не помню какого-то негативного восприятия при переходе на неё. А тут вот что-то прям резануло.

Comment: Да тут проблема, что взяли мерзотный серый, был бы он потемнее - было бы всё ок

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а у меня в emacs тоже темная есть (когда надоедает я перехожу с одной на другую) и тоже нормально. Но в emacs я сам цвета подбирал, там что-то типа редактора есть

Answer (score 5):

## Отлично!

Рад, что тема наконец-то появилась, что наверняка окажется полезным для большого числа участников нашего сообщества.

Answer (score 4):

Попробовал в течении 2-х дней.

Похоже, текст и фон в большинстве мест слишком контрастны, глаза устают.

Вердикт — она хуже светлой.

P.S.
возвращаюсь на сторону света -)

Comment: То, что она хуже, признает и сам ее разработчик, посмотрите статью по ссылке. Если бы темная была лучше, ее бы сделали до светлой. Смысл темной темы в том, чтобы глаза меньше уставали при работе в темноте. Пробовать ее просто так, при обычном освещении, бессмысленно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, ОК, при случае попробую в темноте

Comment: Когда электричество отключат, то будет нормально выглядеть, ага.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight т.е. на Visual Studio тоже надо только в полумраке использовать Dark Mode? Я вот в повседневном режиме так.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ по замыслу именно так. Наиболее комфортно, когда яркость фона соответствует яркости окружения, то есть светлый текст на темном фоне - для работы в темноте. IDE это немного другое, в ней мы больше пишем, чем читаем длинные тексты, поэтому вопрос цветовой темы менее важен. Скорее с программой для чтения электронных книг надо сравнивать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в книге-то уж точно много не попишешь, но вот на сайте мы прямо сейчас формируем его контент, как и в IDE. Так что стоит и способ использования учитывать, кто-то просто читает и голосует, а кто-то пишет, может даже больше, чем в IDE :)