# Темная тема. Замечания и хотелки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Давайте писать свои замечания и пожелания изменений в эту тему.

Comment: Вот бы привычную Darcul'у завезли))

Comment: А почему бы не писать это сразу в качестве ответов под соответствующим [анонсом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10996/176217)? Там и просмотров будет больше, т.к. [meta-tag:важное] установлено.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, именно там Nicolas попросил -- *`"Напишите, пожалуйста, отдельным вопросом либо на нашей Мете, либо на Мете Stack Overflow на английском."`*

Comment: Как хотите, для меня тогда непонятно, что вообще под анонсом обсуждать, если там [meta-tag:обсуждение] висит. Может он не в себе был? Хотя, если размазать по нескольким вопросам, то и активность на сайте как бы возрастёт. Наверное, это хорошо для загнивающих показателей.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала.

1. Пожалуй, я бы поменял цвета текста не просмотренного и уже посещенного вопросов на главной странице. Т.е. начальный цвет сдел бы более ярким.
2. Конечно, идеально было бы иметь редактор темы, с возможностью установки в RGB цветов элементов (background, foreground и т.д.)

---

UPD-1.

Попробовал в течении 2-х дней. Похоже, текст и фон в большинстве мест слишком контрастны, глаза устают.

Вердикт -- она хуже светлой.

P.S.
возвращаюсь на сторону света -)

Comment: Вы, кстати, можете написать свою собственную цветовую тему - емнип у Хрома и Мозиллы точно есть расширения/плагины для кастомизации сайтов.