# Имеет ли смысл задавать вопросы о дефектах мобильной версии?

Tags: обсуждение, мобильная-версия

В комментариях под [этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10996/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bd%d0%b0-stack-overflow-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc) вопросом я увидел фразу:

> мобильная версия, имхо, не развивается вовсе

и возник вопрос, имеет ли смысл задавать вопросы о дефектах мобильной версии?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если речь о проблемах перевода eng - rus, то, безусловно, стоит сообщить об этом на нашей мете с меткой [локализация](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f). Если же дело в каких-то функциональных вещах, то репортить надо на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), т.к. это скорее всего затрагивает и другие сайты (можно на всякий случай проверить перед публикацией).

Дальше уже зависит от серьёзности проблемы будут ли ей действительно заниматься. Т.е. зарепортить с точки зрения зафиксировать проблему - полезно, но не стоит рассчитывать, что её оперативно будут исправлять, особенно, если это какая-то мелочь.

Еще один момент, говорящий о второстепенности мобильной версии — это автоматическое переключение на «полноразмерный вид» для некоторых страниц. И самое неожиданное для меня было то, что это делается даже для [страницы задания вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Вероятно, это связано с внедрением двухфазовой процедуры задания вопроса и прочих ask-wizard.

А [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/339911) нашёлся ответ о планах SO по развитию мобильной версии.

Comment: то что задание вопроса происходит в полной версии это даже хорошо, легко вставлять код и изображение

Comment: @Danis и там тоже [бажно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356339/339911). Глючный SO :)

Comment: @Danis имхо, то же самое, без отступов.

Comment: а где можно попросить чтоб эту мобильную версию вообще выключили? зачем она нужна когда так мешает?

Comment: @DiD её наличие не обязует вас ей пользоваться. Если не пользоваться, то и не мешает. За редким исключением, что иногда может включиться при использовании с мобильного устройства. Но это отключается одной же кнопкой.